# Could not load an assembly despite it being referenced

Tags: c#, .net, google-apps-script, autodesk-navisworks

I'm looking at incorporating the new [Google Apps Script Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/) into an existing C# plugin i have already working. I am following the [.NET quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/dotnet) provided as a console application (which i have gotten working without problem).

When porting the code from that into my plugin it will also fail at runtime at the first instance of:

```
UserCredential credential;
```

which I slimmed down the code so far to just that line which fails giving:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.9.2.27817, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

The file is properly referenced (having installed via nuget).

C# is not my normal field and perhaps i'm missing something in the subtlety of it working in a Console App.

What gives?

Comment: What is the target framework and what type of project is it? Is it a portable class library? Are you sure the DLL file is copied to the output directory?

Comment: yes a class library. i don't think it is copying any dll's to the output directory. it hasn't needed to for the application api's, but i suppose that application is providing them at runtime. is this something to be added as a build event?

Comment: indeed it is. i was copying referenced packages correctly, but as per my own answer below they need to be in a separate Dependencies directory for the application for which i am creating plugins.

Answer (score 1):

There was a time when console apps defaulted to using the client profile rather than the full .Net framework.  Check the properties of the project on the Application tab and make sure the target framework doesn't end with Client profile.  If that doesn't work try using the [fusion log viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx), which you'll find conviently located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin, [or any number of other places](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2014/08/21/where-is-fuslogvw-exe-fusion-log.aspx).  Run it as an admin and it'll tell you what it can't load (which may or may not be Google.Apis.Auth) and where it looked for the file at.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a little bit of a red herring. Not very well documented is the fact for the app i am building against, Autodesk Navisworks, 
plugin dependency libraries have to be duplicated in a separate directory altogether from the plugins directory.

Easily fixed for the build environment, but will need a little more thought for when creating a distributable.